# Convert object array to dictionary in python with a single line of code

Tags: python

I'm a c# person... I'm used to being able to do this without line breaks or colons... is there some method calls like dict(zip(...)) where I can do the following python in a ultra-condensed fashion?

```
cookies = {}
for c in myObject.cookies:
    cookies[c.name] = c.value
```

Comment: BTW: It should be `cookies = {}` in the first line to work.

Comment: Thx, yeah I'm green...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension:

```
cookies = {c.name:c.value for c in myObject.cookies}
```